# Как узнать есть ли хотя бы один виджет

Tags: java, android, виджет

В service хочу узнавать есть ли виджет, но как мне узнать есть ли хоть один виджет на экране?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName( BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Widget.class.getName() );
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance( context );
int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds( componentName );
```

По размеру массива ids можно судить о наличии виджетов на экране.